# Why does Devise/Omniauth add garbage to the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth

After signing in with facebook, I'm being redirected to `/#_=_`, which shows the home page.

This sort of garbage also appeared in other URLs, for example when sign up failed and got redirected to `/users/sign_in#_=_`

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Callback appends '#_=_' to Return URL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url)

Comment: See @Igy comment and goto [question][1].


  [1]: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7131909/facebook-callback-appends-to-return-url

Answer (score 2):

If you really don't want it, some simple javascript and you're good to go :

```
if (window.location.hash == "#_=_") {
    window.location.hash = "";   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is normal in facebook login. Don't worry.